# Installing libgpgme development package on redhat linux 7

Tags: linux

I am trying to install gpg in python by pip but I get below error:

```
Could not find gpgme-config.  Please install the libgpgme development package.
```

My OS is linux 7 , howvee I cant find any rpm to install above package on linux 7 , I have searched [this](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gpgme-devel) webiste but cant find any package for linux 7. Can anyone guide me how to install libgpgme-devel on linux7?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a distribution called "Linux 7", as far as I know at least. Probably you meant Centos 7 or RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 (RHEL7). You can see by looking into the file '/etc/os-release'.

If it is any of the two I mentioned above, you can do:

```
yum provides gpgme-config
```

It will tell you the package name (for centos7 is gpgme-devel), and then do:

```
sudo yum install -y gpgme-devel
```

If this does not work for you, please post the contents of the '/etc/os-release' file.